# Is it possible from preventing Windows from killing a Python process?

Tags: python, windows, python-3.x, windows-7

I'm using the `multiprocessing` module and I get it to create 2 extra processes at about the same time to run 2 different methods. However, about 30 minutes later after the 2nd process started, Windows is killing it.

My question is whether I can prevent this from happening?

Comment: It probably depends why Windows is killing it, doesn't it? So the answer will depend on what the process is doing.

Comment: if the task seems unresponsive for that long perhaps windows is killing it ... are you sure windows is killing it and its not just finishing its task? how are you sure?

Comment: I'm sure the task is not finished because both processes are scraping a website, and when it's done, it writes the information to an Excel file, and I know the 2nd process isn't done because everytime I run it, the 2nd process has different amounts of data each time.

Comment: Windows does not kill processes arbitrarily.  Probably the process is crashing of its own accord, or perhaps it is being killed by malware or by anti-malware software, or perhaps by Python.

Comment: You should add some logging. Try to wrap the entire body of your functions that are running as subprocesses in try/except blocks, and log any exceptions that occur. That should give you more information about the cause of the failure.